# Using Google's Directory API for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-directory-api

I am trying to create my first console app using Google's Directory API for .Net.

I have a code based in a Google's sample. It shows me a couple of errors, **one of them** is when I am trying to create the service:

```
var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   Authenticator = auth,
   ApplicationName = "Create User",
   ApiKey = "<your API Key from Google APIs console>"
 });
```

It shows me: "Error 3   'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' doesn't contain a definition for 'Authenticator'"

And the **second** error is in this function

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg){}
```

It shows me: "DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient'  is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."

In this case I typed (using nuget console): PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -Version 4.3.4.13329 .... but it doesnt resolve my problem.

---

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


using System.Diagnostics;

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
//using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1;
using Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data;


namespace GoogleDirectoryApi_test02_consola
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
        String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

        // Register the authenticator and create the service
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

        //New User
        User newuserbody = new User();
        string userId = "SampleId01";
        UserName newusername = new UserName();
        newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = userId;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth,
            ApplicationName = "Create User",
            ApiKey = "<your API Key from Google APIs console>"
        });


        User results = service.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
    }



    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        // Get the auth URL:
        //IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DirectoryService.Scopes.AdminDirectoryUser.GetStringValue() });
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser.ToString() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();

        // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
    }
}
```

**Thanks in advance for your help**

Comment: see my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868344/batch-request-sendas-emails

Answer (score 2):

have to have a service account with Perform Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority as defined in

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

it say to add it in the "Manage third party OAuth Client access" i had "Manage OAuth Client access "

```
 String serviceAccountEmail = "......@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
                X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new[]
                    {
                        DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser
                    },
                    User = "admin@domain.com"
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                var ser = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Get it to work",
                });

                User newuserbody = new User();
                UserName newusername = new UserName();
                newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = "jack@domain.com";
                newusername.GivenName = "jack";
                newusername.FamilyName = "black";
                newuserbody.Name = newusername;
                newuserbody.Password = "password";

                User results = ser.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```