# Bulk Operations (Create users) in google apps sdk

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I see there are bulk operations for some portions of google apps admin sdk but I'm not seeing one for creating / updating users.  Are there bulk operations for creating and updating user accounts in google apps? (Using the .NET API)

Comment: Do you mean creating and inserting user using Admin sdk? For creating user, check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert and for updating user, check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update . Let me know if your scenario is different.

Comment: Yes, that is the functionality I'm looking for.  However, I'm not seeing it in the .net api but I could be blind...?  Is it called something else?

Comment: You can check this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/admin/directory_v1. Above functionality is available in .NET too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638337/using-googles-directory-api-for-net

Comment: The bottom link is just authorizing to google (I'm already authorized and working with the API; I just want to move some operations to bulk operations...)  But the first link has the process... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch