# Batch Request - SendAs Emails

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts, google-workspace

Is there a way to do a batch request to get SendAs emails from multiple or all users?

Currently we are using a service account with user impersonation to go through each user and get the SendAs email list - lot of requests.

1. GmailService as service - this is impersonated as the user.
2. service.Users.Settings.SendAs.List("me").Execute();

P.S. I posted this in google group, but just read a post that said the forum is now read-only! It's weird that it allowed me to make a new post (and obviously i was thinking that the post has to be approved)

Thanks!

```
    static string[] Scopes = {  GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom,
                                GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsBasic,
                                GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsSharing,
                                GmailService.Scope.GmailModify};

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets default send as email address from user's gmail - throws error if valid domain is not used as default sendAs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="primaryEmailAddress">User's email address to use to impersonate</param>
    /// <param name="excludedDomains">Domains to exclude in the results - example: @xyz.org</param>
    /// <returns>default SendAs email address</returns>
    public static string GetDefaultSendAs(string primaryEmailAddress, string[] excludedDomains)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = 
                Auth.GetServiceAccountAuthorization
                    (scopes: Scopes, clientSecretFilePath: Constant.ClientSecretFilePath, impersonateAs: primaryEmailAddress)
        });


        var result = service.Users.Settings.SendAs.List("me").Execute();

        SendAs s = result.SendAs.First(e => e.IsDefault == true);
        bool incorrectSendAs = false;

        if (s != null)
        {
            foreach (string domain in excludedDomains)
            {
                // Check if email ends with domain
                if (s.SendAsEmail.ToLower().EndsWith("@" + domain.TrimStart('@'))) // removes @ and adds back - makes sure to domain start with @.
                {
                    incorrectSendAs = true;
                }
            }             
        }

        if (s != null && !incorrectSendAs)
            retVal = s.SendAsEmail;
        else
            throw new Exception($"{primaryEmailAddress}, valid default SendAs email not set."); 

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        return retVal;
    }
```

Auth Code:

```
class Auth
{
    internal static ServiceAccountCredential GetServiceAccountAuthorization(string[]scopes, string clientSecretFilePath, string impersonateAs = "admin@xyz.org")
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential retval;

        if (impersonateAs == null || impersonateAs == string.Empty)
        {
            throw new Exception("Please provide user to impersonate");
        }
        else
        {

            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                retval = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                             .CreateScoped(scopes)
                                             .CreateWithUser(impersonateAs)
                                             .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

API client access:
[image: API client access]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your authorization code.   I would like to see how you are logging in with the service account.   And if you wouldnt mind i would love to see a few screen shots from gsuite where you set up the domain delegation of the service account feel free blank out things that shoudnt be shared.

Comment: Updated! Thanks!

Comment: Can some kind of admin see the SendAs email address of other users? Maybe we just need to use some enterprise level admin user for impersonation.

Comment: x my last comment - get a delegation error if we try to use the enterprise admin to get the SendAs of another user.
Error: Message[Delegation denied for admin@xyz.org] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]

Comment: the delegation error still occurs even if impersonation user has delegated access to user's email.

Comment: mentioning @DaImTo, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code i have been looking for an example of user impersonation for years. Questions come up and i have not had a working example to link to as i no longer have access to a gusite account.   Your code may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note on batching**

First I am gong to ask why you are using batching.  If you are hoping it will save you on quota usage it wont batching is effected by the same quota usage as normal api calls.  The only help batching will give you would be in sending fewer HTTP calls and there by spending things up a little.

Each HTTP connection that your client makes results in a certain amount of overhead. The some Google APIs supports batching, to allow your client to put several API calls into a single HTTP request.

The HTTP headers for the outer batch request, except for the Content- headers such as Content-Type, apply to every request in the batch. If you specify a given HTTP header in both the outer request and an individual call, then the individual call header's value overrides the outer batch request header's value. The headers for an individual call apply only to that call.

For example, if you provide an **Authorization header for a specific call, then that header applies only to that call**. If you provide an Authorization header for the outer request, then that header applies to all of the individual calls unless they override it with Authorization headers of their own.

**Authorization**

When you authorize to an api that authorization is for a single user.

```
GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = 
            Auth.GetServiceAccountAuthorization
                (scopes: Scopes, clientSecretFilePath: Constant.ClientSecretFilePath, impersonateAs: primaryEmailAddress)
    });
```

The above service will have access to only that one users data the user which you are impersonating.

**Anwser**

> Is there a way to do a batch request to get SendAs emails from multiple or all users?

No there is not.  As you can read from above the authorization header of a batch request covers all of the items in the batch.  The authorization header created sent with the GmailService for your batch request is only going to cover a single user.

Comment: Reason would be that is just too many request or too much time. If we need to get SendAs list of 1000 users that'll be 1000 requests and it takes forever (~ 3 minutes 40 secs.) I was NOT expecting that there was a way to get a list of all user's emails settings in batch request but had to ask just in-case. And sounds like there isn't so we would probably cache the SendAs for later use.

Comment: Next questions would be that how should we handle updating cache, since we don't see a DateUpdated field in Data.User when SendAs is changed gmail settings which totally makes sense, since mail and user are totally different entities. Any suggestions?

Comment: Flood protection quota is going to keep you from going to fast anyway.

Comment: have you checked out https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Thanks for the link, we'll look into it. Should I mark this as the answer or you think there is another way to make the service request that would have access to all users settings? so we could use other usernames in this code than just me or* current user service.Users.Settings.SendAs.List("me").Execute();

Comment: I dont think there is going to be a way of getting a batch request to work with more then one user.   I have never seen much point with batching anyway.  You are welcome to leave the question open to see if anyone else responds.  However if you check my profile i think that you will notice i am the one who anwsers most of the google api questions :)